# Why do I sometimes have to specify what app I'm targeting in heroku?

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I have two different applications deployed to heroku. Inside one of them, to access a production console I have to type:

```
heroku run rails console
```

However, in the other one, the CLI barks at me when I don't specify the application with `-a foo` / `--a=foo`. I end up typing this:

```
heroku run rails console -a seaweed-soup
```

Running the command with `--help` shows me some inconsistent advice:

```
➜  seaweed-soup (master) ✔ heroku run rails console --help
run a one-off process inside a heroku dyno

USAGE
  $ heroku run

OPTIONS
  -a, --app=app        (required) parent app used by review apps
  -e, --env=env        environment variables to set (use ';' to split multiple vars)
...
```

The app flag **isn't really required**, since I'm able to run the command without it in the other repo. So presumably, at some point I've configured one of the repositories to have the value of `app` set somewhere useful. However, I haven't found anything in [the docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands), and `env` isn't showing anything promising.

My only other thought is that the `.git/config` files look slightly different, but there's no chance that I modified those by hand, so I'm assuming there's some approved way of configuring this. Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: What does `git remote -v` show? I think Heroku uses the remote to determine which app you want to interact with.

Comment: Aha - in the app that's configured usefully, `git remote -v` shows a heroku repo, and seaweed soup doesn't. This pointed me in the right direction, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comment above, my git remote repositories were configured differently. I did some searching and found [useful documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#creating-a-heroku-remote). By running:

```
heroku git:remote -a seaweed-soup
```

My git config used to look like this:

```
...
[heroku]
    remote = seaweed-soup
```

Running the command above made it look like this:

```
...
[heroku]
    remote = seaweed-soup
[remote "seaweed-soup"]
    url = https://git.heroku.com/seaweed-soup.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/seaweed-soup/*
```

So I've manually removed the outdated (malformed?) entry, assuming that the formatting has quietly changed or that I configured something incorrectly a long time ago.